# How to push into an array on submit in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and trying to implement simple todo app. But, upon submit I am not able to push into an array i.e a state variable.

Following is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class ToDo extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={list:['hello'],item:''}
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleSearchChange=this.handleSearchChange.bind(this)
}
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(state=>({list:(state.list.push(this.state.item))}))

}
handleSearchChange(e){
    this.setState({item:e.target.value})
}

render(){
    console.log('state:',this.state.list)
    let listing=this.state.list.map((item)=><li key={item}>{item}</li>)
    return(
            <div >
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <label>
                    <input className="form-control "type="text" value={this.state.item} onChange={this.handleSearchChange} />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="form-control" />
                    </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <ul>{listing}</ul>
            </div>

        )
}
}

export default ToDo;
```

When I try to click on submit it redirects to error.
Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't mutate state directly. make a copy of state and than push value into it and than  use setState.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
handleSubmit(e){
        const { list, item } = this.state
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ list: [...list, item] })
}
```

Explaination: you can't mutate data, concatenate it like this instead.
Advice: use es6 functions always, so you will never need binding.

Comment: Thanks. Can u also tell i to do splice opertaion in same situation if i do have a index.

Comment: Yeah I ll tell you if you select my answer as I answered before ;)

Comment: `this.setState({list:[...this.state.list.splice(index,1)]})` will this work ?

Comment: Its better to let the list this.state.list with full data. Then you could slice it when you call the state like this: this.state.list.slice().map((item)=><li key={item}>{item}</li>. Use slice instead splice because slice create a new array in contrary to slice (for immutability concern)

Comment: also another advice, try to use const instead let for best practice, necessity of let is very rare (I almost never use it personally), because anyway your page rerender: const listing=this.state.list.map((item)=><li key={item}>{item}</li>.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy and helpful to you...

```
handleSubmit(e){
  const {list, item}=this.state;
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ list: [...list, item] });
}
```